# Add click events to ToolStripTextBox in VB.NET when created in code

Tags: vb.net

I am creating tabs to keep track of open files. When I create them I can set their properties and add them to the list in a MenuStrip.

Before I do so I want to add a click event function. Since this is in a function and will be run multiple times, I need to have a dynamic way to do add these event handlers. I cannot write this:

```
Private Sub ToolStripTextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripTextBox1.Click
    ' ...
End Sub
```

If I do this I can only name them all one name. I want to be able to add a click event that applies to them separately as individual items.

UPDATE:

```
Dim textFile As ToolStripTextBox = New ToolStripTextBox("textFile")
FileList.Items.Add(textFile)
textFile.Text = filename
textFile.ReadOnly = True
textFile.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(61, 61, 61)
textFile.ForeColor = Color.White
```

This is the creation and personalization code. Though when you guys suggested `AddButton_Click() Handles AddButton.Click` It doesn't work because AddButton isn't an actual button

Comment: Show the code adding the items to the menustrip

Comment: You *can* use the same handler. The `event` to the handler will have an `event.target` that identifies which element got clicked. Do you need more than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the items, add add and remove click handlers with the following code

```vb
Private FileList As New List(Of ToolStripItem)()

' put this code where you add an item
    Dim filename = "whatever"
    Dim textFile As ToolStripTextBox = New ToolStripTextBox(filename)
    textFile.Text = filename
    textFile.ReadOnly = True
    textFile.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(61, 61, 61)
    textFile.ForeColor = Color.White
    add(textFile)

Private Sub clickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim item = DirectCast(sender, ToolStripItem)
    MessageBox.Show(item.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub add(textFile As ToolStripItem)
    FileList.Add(textFile) ' Since I don't know what FileList is, I ued List
    AddHandler textFile.Click, AddressOf clickHandler
    OpenProjectToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(textFile) ' add to whatever menu item you normally do
End Sub

Private Sub remove(textFile As ToolStripItem)
    FileList.Remove(textFile)
    RemoveHandler textFile.Click, AddressOf clickHandler
    OpenProjectToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Remove(textFile)
End Sub
```

Comment: AddButton isn't a button so the sub doesn't work

Comment: Ya I made that to test your code, since you hadn't supplied it by then. It should be simple enough to make this work in your environment

Comment: Okay so name when making GUID can just be the name and text of the toolstripTextBox?

Comment: Yes I will update my answer based on your code

Answer (score 0):

The sample click event in your code includes this:

```
sender As Object
```

You can re-use this one event handler, because whichever menu item is clicked will be the `sender`. So you do something like this:

```
Private Sub ToolStripTextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ToolStripTextBox1.Click
    Dim menuItem = DirectCast(sender,  ToolStripMenuItem)
    If menuItem Is Nothing Then Return

    'If you need to choose different code for each item:
    Select Case menuItem.name
         Case "some item"

         Case "some other item"

    End Select
End Sub
```

And you can connect your dynamic toolstrip items to this method using `AddHandler`:

```
AddHandler myMenuStrip.Click, AddressOf ToolSTripTextBox1_Click
```

Comment: I don't follow ToolStripTextBox1 is one of the existing and I reuse the same handler?

Comment: Yes. You can re-use the same handler.